# Python client for AWS Redis Cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, client, cluster-computing

Can anyone suggest a Python client for AWS Redis Cluster enabled?

I'm using redis-py-cluster, but it fails:

Sample code:

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster
startup_nodes = [{"host": "xxxx.clustercfg.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com", "port": "6379"}]
r = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True, skip_full_coverage_check=False)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
value = r.get('foo')
```

======
Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testRedisCluster.py", line 11, in
r = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True, skip_full_coverage_check=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/client.py", line 181, in init
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/connection.py", line 141, in init
self.nodes.initialize()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 228, in initialize
need_full_slots_coverage = self.cluster_require_full_coverage(nodes_cache)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 270, in cluster_require_full_coverage
return any(node_require_full_coverage(node) for node in nodes.values())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 270, in
return any(node_require_full_coverage(node) for node in nodes.values())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 267, in node_require_full_coverage
return "yes" in r_node.config_get("cluster-require-full-coverage").values()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 715, in config_get
return self.execute_command('CONFIG GET', pattern)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 668, in execute_command
return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 680, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 629, in read_response
raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'CONFIG'
```

I'm using redis-py-cluster 1.3.4.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Change the parameter skip_full_coverage_check=False to skip_full_coverage_check=True